# Picasso - Target must not be null

Tags: java, android

whenever a new intent opens, it stays on that page for a Second and the application will be force closed.Someone help me out how to debug this run time error.

```
public class FoodDetails extends AppCompatActivity {


ImageView img_food;

String foodId="";
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference foods;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_details);

    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    foods = database.getReference("foods");

    numberButton = (ElegantNumberButton)findViewById(R.id.number_button);
    btncart = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.btncart);
    food_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_description);
    food_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_name);
    food_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.food_price);
    img_food = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_food);

    collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)findViewById(R.id.collapsing);

    collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.ExtendedAppbar);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppbar);

    if(getIntent()!=null)
        foodId = getIntent().getStringExtra("FoodId");
    if(!foodId.isEmpty()){
        getDetailFood(foodId);
    }
}

private void getDetailFood(String foodId) {
    foods.child(foodId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Food food = dataSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
            Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage())
                    .into(img_food);

            collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(food.getName());
            food_price.setText(food.getPrice());
            food_name.setText(food.getName());
            food_description.setText((food.getDescription()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Stack trace of the error and this is the line where the error is 
at com.k.menu.FoodDetails$1.onDataChange(FoodDetails.java:63)

```
    01-14 21:53:25.446 10015-10015/com.k.menu E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                        Process: com.k.menu, PID: 10015
                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Target must not be null.
                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:618)
                                                            at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:601)
                                                            at com.k.menu.FoodDetails$1.onDataChange(FoodDetails.java:64)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzegf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeia.zzbyc(Unknown Source)
                                                            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeig.run(Unknown Source)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

My model food class

```
public class Food {

private String Name,Image,Description,Price,MenuId;

public Food() {
}

public Food(String name, String image, String description, String price, String menuId) {
    Name = name;
    Image = image;
    Description = description;
    Price = price;
    MenuId = menuId;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return Image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    Image = image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return Description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    Description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    Price = price;
}

public String getMenuId() {
    return MenuId;
}

public void setMenuId(String menuId) {
    MenuId = menuId;
}
```

}

Comment: And what's on line 63?

Comment: Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage().into(img_food)

Comment: The food object is null. You should check that what is stored in firebase matches the class you are trying to serialize it in to. Do the names match, etc....

Comment: yes they do match

Comment: can you show your database structure?

Comment: debug by putting a breakpoint at line 63. check food object

Comment: @DanielB this is what i got when i put breakpoint.......dataSnapshot: "DataSnapshot {Key=08, value= null }" and food_image = null

Comment: @Napster https://www.dropbox.com/s/fdci1f6qvf6ysai/IMG_20180114_202937.jpg?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the reason why you aren't getting any data is your database reference. Inside your database structure you have a child called "Foods" where as the child you are fetching is "foods". Change

`foods = database.getReference("foods");`

to

`foods = database.getReference("Foods");`

Comment: {
"rules":  {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
        "Foods":{
          ".indexOn":["MenuId"]
}}}     is this right???

Comment: now stack trace shows error is in 64line and debuger shows this error   Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(food.getImage())  food: foods@5685

Comment: same it force closes but the old error it was like the intent opens then force close

Comment: Can you paste the whole stacktrace in your question?

Comment: That means that your `ImageView` layout called `image_id` that you are putting the image into is null